# Firebase Cloud Messaging not export to BigQuery suddenly

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM has been successfully exported to BigQuery for 3 months, but entering September, it suddenly could not be exported. What could be causing this? How should I resolve this issue?

The error message is like this:
Invalid value: Invalid credential; JobID: xxxxxxxx

I have checked the permissions of the account used for the transfer and inspected the quotas for BigQuery, and everything seems to be fine.